# Erro no Checkbox

Tags: php, checkbox, if

Preciso fazer um `while` no **PHP**:

```
  while($lo = mysql_fetch_array($ro)) {
      $id3 = $lo["id"];
      $nome_menor = utf8_encode($lo["nome_menor"]);
```

Isso está ok! Esta mostrando o nome das empresas listadas na **query** abaixo:

```
$ro = mysql_query("select * from empresa order by nome_menor");
```

Mas agora preciso fazer um `if` dentro do `while`

Preciso que o `if` verifique na tabela de checkbox se o nome da variável do `while` está com 1 ou 0, pensei em algo assim:

```
$rz = mysql_query("select * from mulempresa where (id_contrato = $id2) ");
$ck1 = mysql_fetch_array($rz,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

  $checked = "";
  if($ck1[$nome_menor] == 1)
  $checked3 = "checked=checked";
```

Mas está dando o seguinte erro:

```
"Notice: Undefined index"
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: melhor você postar o código inteiro. Pois o erro pode estar em outro lugar. Geralmente, esse erro é causado porque você não resgatou uma variável. Por isso ela está indefinida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenta dessa forma >

```
$rz = mysql_query("select * from mulempresa where id_contrato = $id2 ");
    $ck1 = mysql_fetch_array($rz);
    while ($lo = mysql_fetch_array($ro)) {
        $id3 = $lo["id"];
        $nome_menor = utf8_encode($lo["nome_menor"]);
        $checked = "";
        if ($ck1[$nome_menor] == 1) {
            $checked = "checked='checked'";
        }
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$id3}' onclick='return false' value='on' {$checked} />{$nome_menor}<br/>";
    }
```

OBS:  Existe um grande problema nesse if > `if ('$ck1[$nome_menor]' == 1)`.  aspas simples não vai printar o valor da sua variável e sim o nome. Já aspas duplas faz o contrário, ou seja, printa o valor da variável.

Comment: Infelizmente não foi, dá esse erro: Notice: Undefined index ( Nome da coluna da tabela que consta na consulta) !

Comment: a Tabela é assim: Exatamente o nome $nome_menor como nome da coluna e 0 ou 1 como valor dentro de cada empresa

Comment: de um print_r no $rz e cole aqui se possível

Comment: Resolvi! Troquei o nome_menor por um contador!
obrigado!

Comment: Que bom, estava verificando o seu  o array de $rz e não tinha encontrado o indice 'nome_menor'

Answer (score 1):

Deixa assim:

```
 $checked3 = "checked";

 echo "<input type='checkbox' name='$id3' onclick='return false' value='on' ". $checked3 ." /> ".$nome_menor." <br/> ";
```

Deve resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi! Troquei a variável por um contador! Baseada na posição do array, aí eu coleto o dado lá dentro! 
Obrigado à Ajuda de todos!
Segue código:

```
    <?php
$i=1;
$rz = mysql_query("select * from mulempresa where id_contrato = $id2 ");
    $ck1 = mysql_fetch_array($rz);
    print_r($ck1);
    while ($lo = mysql_fetch_array($ro)) {
        $id3 = $lo["id"];
        $nome_menor = utf8_encode($lo["nome_menor"]);
        $checked = "";

        if ($ck1[$i] == 1) {
            $checked = "checked='checked'";
        }
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='{$id3}' onclick='return false' value='on' {$checked} />{$nome_menor}<br/>";
$i = $i + 1;
}?>
```